# Modify field in csv file with Python

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to remove special characters from a specific column within my csv file. But I cant figure out a way to specify the column I would like to change. Here is what I have:

```
import csv    

input_file = open('src/list.csv', 'r')
output_file = open('src/list_new.csv', 'w')
data = csv.reader(input_file)
writer = csv.writer(output_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)  # dialect='excel')
specials = '#'

for line in data:
    line = str(line)
    new_line = str.replace(line, specials, '')
    writer.writerow(new_line.split(','))

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Instead of searching through the whole file how can I specify the column ("Names") I would like to remove the special characters from?

Comment: In order to change the whole file you have to read the whole file (and then write) the whole file. What you should not be doing is converting the parsed line to a string which completely defeats the purpose of using a csv parser. You can refer to the column by index in the returned parsed tuple  or by name if you use a dictreader.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use csv.DictReader? Then you can refer to the column by name.